# Error: control may reach end of non-void function in C++

Tags: c++, controls

I cannot figure out why this error is happening: error: "control may reach end of non-void function" even when "else" statement is present at the end.

Here is the code:

```
bnode* binsert(bnode *h,int k){
    bnode *temp=new bnode;
    if(h==NULL)
    {
        temp->num=k;
        temp->L=NULL;
        temp->R=NULL;
        h=temp;
        return h;
    }
    else if(h->L==NULL && k<h->num)
    {
        temp->num=k;
        temp->L=NULL;
        temp->R=NULL;
        h->L=temp;
        return h;
    }
    else if(h->R==NULL && k>h->num)
    {
        temp->num=k;
        temp->L=NULL;
        temp->R=NULL;
        h->R=temp;
        return h;
    }
    else if(h->L!=NULL && k<h->num)
    {
        h->L=binsert(h->L,k);
    }
    else
    {
        h->R=binsert(h->R,k);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to be returned in your last two branches of if's? Perhaps you meant `return h->R=binsert(h->R,k);`?

Comment: in general it isnt that simple for a compiler to make sure that every branch returns, though this is a case where it is quite easy to realize that there is no return on some branches ;)

Comment: I would just add `return h;` at the end and remove the other 3 returns.

Comment: What's so hard to understand? The error message is pretty clear about what the problem is (and it's pretty trivial to spot). Just look at your code, trace the various control flows, look for paths where you can reach the end of the function without ever returning a value - those cases are your bug(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the results of recursive calls, it's not done automatically.

You can also simplify your code a bit by adding a constructor:

```
bnode::bnode(int v)
    : num(v),
      L(nullptr),
      R(nullptr)
{

}
```

and since you're already handling the case of a null parameter, you don't need special cases for null children:

```
bnode* binsert(bnode *h,int k)
{
    if(h == nullptr)
    {
        h = new bnode(k);
    }
    else if(k < h->num)
    {
        h->L = binsert(h->L, k);
    }
    else if(k > h->num)
    {
        h->R = binsert(h->R, k);
    }
    return h;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because this last 2 conditions:

```
else if(h->L!=NULL && k<h->num)
{
    h->L=binsert(h->L,k);
}
else
{
    h->R=binsert(h->R,k);
}
```

may occur and no return is given...

you need to be sure the function  returns a value no matter what the condition evaluates....

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(h->L!=NULL && k<h->num)
{
    h->L=binsert(h->L,k);
}
else
{
    h->R=binsert(h->R,k);
}
```

In the `else if` and `else` cases for your code, if you reach here, you do not return a value, and the behavior is undefined if you try to use this value.

You probably want to add a `return h;` in the two branches.